# How to add css classes to laravel nova fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm not so familiar with Laravel nova and need some help please.
Is there a way to add css classes to Laravel nova fields?
I saw somewhere on the web that you could do this:
`Text::make('Name')->hideFromIndex()->sortable()->rules('required')->withMeta(['class' => 'bg-dark']),`

but did not work.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a custom theme? Add properties to your specific inputs if the styling is input specific and style them with your custom css in your theme?

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/themes.html